# Conversion of png with alpha channel to jpg (without causing background artifacts)

Tags: command-line, convert, image-processing, imagemagick, png

How can I convert a png file using terminal or maybe a Python script to a jpg without artifacts?

Here's an example of what I tried showing the artifacts I'm getting:

[image: original image of a cat]

```
jalal@klein:~$ convert cat.png cat.jpg
jalal@klein:~$ eog cat.jpg
```

[image: image with distorted background]

```
jalal@klein:~$ convert cat.png -quality 95 cat_95.jpg
jalal@klein:~$ eog cat_95.jpg
```

[image: same issue]

Comment: Not helpful to your question (and I'm glad someone found a solution to the problem!), but I'll just note that the problem you've discovered could be a cool basis for glitch art.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are suffering from issues due to the alpha channel in your PNG.
You can remove this and replace with a background of you choice using the following command:

```
convert cat.png -background white -alpha remove cat.jpg
```

Comment: wow!! Smart! so much thanks! http://imgur.com/a/E7hmk